# Xcode tests hang

Tags: ios, xcode

I've added a test target to my ios project, leaving for the time being the pre filled test code in the newly created file which has a few methods - set up, tear down and a failing test called testExample. My normal application target builds and runs fine.

When I run the tests, they also build fine with no warnings however the test never fails as it should. In the progress bar at the top of the IDE it has a spinning icon and the words "Indexing" and "Paused".

I've checked for breakpoints - there are none.

In the log navigator I can see my current test build running however again with a spinning icon. Really not sure why its paused.

Using Xcode 5.0.2, XCTest, iPad iOS Simulator.

Comment: Are you testing on pre-iOS 7? I've noticed that this happens on iOS6 and I've presumed that it's not supported on earlier versions.

Comment: My base sdk is set to iOS 7.0. So no don't think so.

Comment: What is the *device* you are testing on?

Comment: Using IOS Simulator 7.0 - iPad

Comment: I ended up deleting my entire test target and starting from scratch.

Comment: Anybody else been able to fix this?  I'm having trouble with it with iOS 8.3 and XCode 6.3 building to an iPad Air 2.  Hate to start from scratch

Answer (score 9):

I also had a hang on test launch which I resolved by resetting the simulator.

Answer (score 5):

Open the Simulator app, **Device -> Restart**.

Answer (score -1):

Device restart did not help in my case, I checked the code and found that I have a Switch loop that did not have a break statement and therefore it hung.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31246985)